# python parser TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I'm relative new to python and I am trying to run an open-sourced project from my windows command prompt. However, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\algofx\trading>python trading.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trading.py", line 74, in <module>
    prices = HistoricCSVPriceHandler(pairs, events, csv_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\algofx\data\price.py", lin
e 112, in __init__
    self.file_dates[self.cur_date_idx]
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\algofx\data\price.py", lin
e 148, in _open_convert_csv_files_for_day
    names=("Time", "Ask", "Bid", "AskVolume", "BidVolume")
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", lin
e 498, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", lin
e 275, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", lin
e 586, in __init__
    self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", lin
e 683, in _clean_options
    _validate_header_arg(options['header'])
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line
 216, in _validate_header_arg
    raise TypeError("Passing a bool to header is invalid. "
TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or
 header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column name
s
```

I'm not sure what to do with this error. This is part of the script of `trading.py`:

```
 #create the historic tick data streaming class        
 prices = HistoricCSVPriceHandler(pairs, events, csv_dir)
```

part of `price.py` under the `class HistoricCSVPriceHandler:`

```
def _open_convert_csv_files_for_day(self, date_str):
    """
    Opens the CSV files from the data directory, converting
    them into pandas DataFrames within a pairs dictionary.

    The function then concatenates all of the separate pairs
    for a single day into a single data frame that is time 
    ordered, allowing tick data events to be added to the queue 
    in a chronological fashion.
    """
    for p in self.pairs:
        pair_path = os.path.join(self.csv_dir, '%s_%s.csv' % (p, date_str))
        self.pair_frames[p] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
            pair_path, header=True, index_col=0, 
            parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True,
            names=("Time", "Ask", "Bid", "AskVolume", "BidVolume")
        )
        self.pair_frames[p]["Pair"] = p
    return pd.concat(self.pair_frames.values()).sort().iterrows()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the error right there:

> TypeError: Passing a `bool` to header is invalid. **Use `header=None`** for no header or
>    `header=int` or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names

And the piece of code that triggers it is:

```
self.pair_frames[p] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
            pair_path, header=True, index_col=0, 
            parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True,
            names=("Time", "Ask", "Bid", "AskVolume", "BidVolume")
        )
```

Specifically `header=True` since `True` is a boolean value and therefore invalid in this case.
You can change the `header` to `header = None` or anything else like the message suggests.

Comment: You are right, I have confused it with another API. Therefore I deleted my post and upvoted yours :-) Thanks!